# How do I block someone else's domain pointing to my hosted website?

Tags: .htaccess

Hi I am running my website in Linux VPS with dedicated IP few weeks ago I found someone else domain is pointing to my website

Ex :: mydomain.com === server my site content otherdomain.com === also server my site content If I update or modify its getting updated on other domain too..

please need help any settings to prevent this

after searching many forums I found the name based virtual host how to implement this in VPS Linux please guide me or any other solution for this issue please help

I also try to see the reverse IP lookup my IP shows two domain another 1 is bad domain is pointing my server/ IP but it server my site content ..how to stop this please help

Comment: Identical question on StackOverflow (from 2 years ago): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236810/how-do-i-block-someone-elses-domain-pointing-to-my-apache-hosted-website

Comment: Blatantly ripping of another question that even has been answered is completely inacceptable, as is spamming your question across multiple sites.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward thing to do here is to create a new [virtualhost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) that accepts connections for the other host and to then display a simple page to them. If the other host is example.com create a virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  DocumentRoot /path/to/documentroot
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236810/how-do-i-block-someone-elses-domain-pointing-to-my-apache-hosted-website), in short, you want to use [virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/) to redirect the incoming request to a different page.

Edit: Also, you could contact the provider for these dodgy records and let them know the details.

Comment: how can i edit my virtualhost file to add  this text " <VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example2
ServerName www.example.org
</VirtualHost>"